# Dynamic Updates for React-Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native, app-update

I have a react-native application currently deployed on both google's play-store and apple's app-store. I want to do two things - **forcefully update the app on all devices** every time a new build with breaking changes is deployed to the store And **dynamically update the app** on all devices on minor bugs fixes.

Regarding the second thing I've heard about **CodePush** handling the work of dynamic app updates but I'm not sure whether to use it or not.

Any help regarding the ***available packages that I can use*** to make user forcefully update apps from respective stores and *whether I should use CodePush or is there anything else that i can use for dynamic updates* would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you finally do? I'm in the same situation

Comment: I end up using CodePush. It's awesome. Now I only deploy new builds when there are changes in native code. Correspondingly I make a code-push release prompting the user to update the app whenever their is a native change. Rest all cases doesn't even need prompting.

Comment: How did you use please elaborate. I need same help. +1 upvote.

Comment: You need to create an account at [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms/create-account). And integrate [react-native-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) in your project.